# Translate javafx GUI into fxml

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am new to fxml, at first it seemed easy to use, but when I gave myself an exercise to translate one of the demo on oracle into fxml, and I found myself spending all day on google.

but still I can't find the answer to these two:

```
btnAdd.setMaxHeight(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
btnAdd.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

if someone know where I can find a tutorial, please share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`fx:constant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#constant_elements):

```
<Button fx:id="btnAdd">
    <maxHeight><Control fx:constant="USE_PREF_SIZE" /></maxHeight>
    <maxWidth><Double fx:constant="MAX_VALUE" /></maxWidth>
</Button>
```

Comment: thank you very much. netbeans doesn't recognise Control fx:constant but it works.